# XSLT help in declaring namespace

Tags: xslt

need some help in resolving the following issue. I need to transform the below input(XML) to the mentioned output(XML).

```
   <Header>
      <End_Date xsi:nil="true"/>
   <Header>
```

To the following format.

```
   <Header>
      <End_Date xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
   <Header>
```

This is the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">  

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  

    <xsl:template match="/">  
      <HEADER>  
        <xsl:for-each select="HEADER">  
          <xsl:sequence select="(./@node(), ./node())"/>
        </xsl:for-each>  
      </HEADER>  
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance.
Gabriel

Comment: I don't see any XML at all (no angle brackets). Even if you had `<END_DATE xsi:nil="true"/>` you couldn't process it with XSLT as it needs namespace well-formed XML to start with and without any xmlns:xsi="someURI" that snippet is not namespace well-formed XML.

Comment: Hi, I can't add any angle brackets. i had a list of code but i can't show it as i don't have enough reputation.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <HEADER>
   <xsl:for-each select="HEADER">
    <xsl:sequence select="(./@node(), ./node())"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </HEADER>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: This is the best i can display this piece of code :S

Comment: @Gabriel you can update your question and provide code samples.  In order to get XML, XSLT, or any other code block to show up as code, either highlight the text and click on the "010101" button, or wrap it in grave accent characters (`)

Comment: This question makes no sense. There is NO XML document provided, there is NO required result provided, there is NO required properties of the transformation provided, the XSLT code provided has NO matching source XML document and there is NO information provided what is wrong with the XSLT code. I VOTE to `CLOSE` this "question"

Comment: @Gabriel: Your request makes no sense. If you have this element in your wellformed input `<END_DATE xsi:nil="true"/>` or you can produce this in a wellformed output, It means that `xsi` prefix is bound to some URI, otherwise nether input or output would be wellformed. Here there is something you are not telling to us.

Comment: Hi all, sorry just got to know how to display the input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in thinking you want to reproduce a nearly exact copy of the input XML, with the addition of the xsi namespace declaration that is lacking from the input?

First, as it is now, your input is not well-formed XML, just because of the lacking xsi namespace declaration. Hence, there's no way to use XSLT for adding it: any XSLT processor will choke on the input's non-well-formedness.

Second, you have to check case sensitivity: currently, no input nodes are matched by the `<xsl:for-each select="HEADER">` select expression. If you change it to `"Header"`, the template rule will indeed replace the `<Header>` input with `<HEADER>`, whose content is copied identically. But... only if you have the namespace declarations in the input right...

So, if the purpose is indeed to 'upgrade' non-well-formed XML to a well-formed version, I'd suggest to look for other tools, such as Perl, Awk, or any other simple search/replace solution that operates on plain text and could just add the missing namespace declaration to the document element:

```
<Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <End_Date xsi:nil="true"/>
</Header>
```

(Of course, you could also make use of XSLT 2.0's `unparsed-text($href)` function that lets you read any file as unparsed text, which you could then further process with `<xsl:analyze-string>`. See Michael Kay's article [Up-conversion using XSLT 2.0](http://www.saxonica.com/papers/ideadb-1.1/mhk-paper.xml) for further inspiration.  Since this a rather awkward way to process non-XML with an XML tool, I give this merely for completeness -- if adding the namespace prefix is the only problem to be solved, I'd definitely go for a cheaper search/replace option.)

Hope this helps,

Ron